# Parsing XML with redundant namespace

Tags: xml, namespaces, jaxb

I am currently faced with an XML where I don't quite understand the syntax.

The syntax is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root xmlns="http://blubb.com/"> 
  <element>
    <element2 xmlns:ns1="http://blubb.com/" xmlns="">
    </element2>
  </element>
</root>
```

The global namespace and the ns1 are identic. Except for the namespaces the shema is vaild against a given xsd. The xsd does only contain one namespace (the global).

Actually I've now got two questions:

(1) To better understand what I've got: Is there any reason why the same namespace is declared? Could there be any advantage? Or is that simply wrong?

(2) When parsing this with JAXB the unmarshalling fails with with the error message below. The XML is provided in this syntax and cannot be changed. Is there any way to ignore the redudant namespace to being able to parse the document?

```
Invalid content was found starting with element ...
...is expected
```

Happy for any assistance!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the following document `element2` is not namespace qualified so the default namespace is being set to "".  The `http://blubb.com/` namespacespace has then been assigned to the `ns1` prefix in case it is needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root xmlns="http://blubb.com/"> 
  <element>
    <element2 xmlns:ns1="http://blubb.com/" xmlns="">
    </element2>
  </element>
</root>
```

**For More Information on JAXB and Namespaces**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html